# Preventing image files being added to browser cache

Tags: html, jquery, image, caching

My application presents image files to the user (for photographic competition judging). It may present several thousand quite large files during a single session.
To present each image, I obtain a URL via a webservice using AJAX and then cause it to be displayed with

> $("#imgImage").prop('src', resp.URL);

I am concerned about the storage usage within the user's browser. Will each image be added to the cache and if so, how can I prevent it?
I have the meta directives

> ```
> <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
> <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1" />
> ```

but as the page itself is not reloaded each time, I'm not sure if they are effective.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the server send those headers with the HTTP response providing the *images*. In your page, they only apply to your page, not the images.

Beware that if your page ever shows the same image again (can the user go back? I'd want to be able to), the client will have to re-download it. If it's large, or they're on a metered connection, that may not be ideal.

Comment: Thanks, but the images don't come as an HTTP response - the URL is obtained via a webservice and I change the src property in the DOM

Comment: @ilens - Right -- and setting `src` triggers an HTTP request, and you serve the caching headers with the response to that request. The only exceptions would be if it's a `data://` or `file://` URL. If it's a `data://` URL, the data is **in** the URL so caching headers aren't relevant. If it's a `file://` URL, I have to admit I don't know if browser cache those (I hope not, it doesn't make sense), but you can't set any caching headers on those either.

Comment: @ilens - That doesn't matter.

Comment: @ilens - Which, again, will trigger a request to the server using the same scheme as the page (`http:` or `https:`, presumably), which will involve a response, which is where you set the the response headers.

Comment: Sorry, I'm missing something here... My server side code doesn't get invoked, so haow can I set response headers?

Comment: @ilens - A server **does** get called to serve the image; otherwise, where would it come from? :-) That server needs to be the one that includes caching control headers.

Comment: I think it must uses a mechanism similar to FTP as my code is not invoked

Comment: @ilens - No, it's not FTP if you're using a relative URL in a web page. (It could be if you were using one starting with `ftp://` but you don't seem to be.) It sounds like whatever server technology you're using, it only "invokes" your code for certain resources and not others.